# Dividing array into sub-arrays based on number of groups

Tags: javascript

This is kind of confusing so I will just demonstrate. I would like to create a function that takes an array like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

...and returns an array of arrays like this:

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4]]
```

assuming that the user wanted 4 groups. Notice that the elements are added to each group before 5th element is added back to the first.

Is there a simple way to do this? My project is using webpack, so I am open to ES6+ or even lodash. Thanks!

Comment: Please also explain what you are trying to do, what happens if the array has an even number of elements?

Comment: And what's the pattern?
I mean, why it's 1 with 5 and not 1 with 6?

Comment: @Luca Well, I am rearranging an array of DOM elements but I thought the number examples was simpler. If perhaps there were 10 elements and 4 groups, it would look like `[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7], [4, 8]]`

Comment: @MitcaVicentiu There are 4 groups, and so 1 through 4 go in the first groups, and then 5 starts back at the very first, six to the second, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
var numGroups= 4;
var result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].reduce(function(acc, ele, idx) {
    var i = idx % numGroups;
    (acc[i] == undefined) ?  acc[i] = [ele] : acc[i].push(ele);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! If you wouldn't mind, could you just give a very brief explanation?